# Add "inch: symbol to label

Tags: labeling

I'm using QGIS 3.23-Bonn on a Win 7 machine. I'm trying to add the "inch" symbol to a label, but can't figure it out. I've tried using `(Diameter) || '\' "` but it doesn't work. However for length in feet this works `(Shape_Length,0)||'\" || '\n' || Diameter`. This displays two labels, stacked. One is in feet and one is in inches. All I need for another one is "inches".

Comment: If you only need the symbol, you enter `...||' "'`. Somehow your description sounds more complex.

Answer (score 2):

As @Erik pointed out, you only need to **include a double quote character inside single quotes**. Use the double pipe (concatenate) operator to append the double quote onto the end of your diameter value.

In the example below, I have `DIAM || '"'`.
[image]